# Excel Function to Average 6 Cells to the left of target cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet of data which includes information from the last few years. Each month, a new column is added, and a lot of the AVERAGE formulas break.

Essentially, what I need is a function that will select 6 cells based on their proximity to the function cell.

Ex: The function in Cell J should select the 6 cells to its left (same row), and if a new column is added, moving this function to K, it should continue to only draw from the 6 cells to its left, potentially including the new one.

Comment: So any data to show what you mean clearly? And what have you tried so far? What have you searched for on here? like finding the last occupied cell?

Comment: Is each column given the month as a header? then use index with match based on the date ie month.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming at least 6 columns, try:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(1:1,SEQUENCE(6,,COLUMN()-6)))
```

Or, 1 upto 5 columns on the left only:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(1:1,LET(X,SEQUENCE(6,,COLUMN()-6),FILTER(X,X>0))))
```

---

Ignore potential empty cells between formula and last 6 values; empty cells in between values themselves are also ignored:

```
=AVERAGE(LET(X,INDEX(1:1&"",SEQUENCE(COLUMN()-1)),Y,--FILTER(X,X<>""),INDEX(Y,SEQUENCE(MIN(COUNT(Y),6),,COUNT(Y),-1))))
```

Comment: The first one works fine if it is in the next column following the data but if it is two or three columns further on the average returned is incorrect.

Comment: @SolarMike, OP states it's about 6 averaging 6 cells to the left of the one holding the formula. Can you elaborate what you mean with "two or three columns further"?

Comment: So if n is the column number of the last cell with data then the function can be in n+2 or n+3, or better that the function works independent of position.

Comment: @SolarMike, something like update might cater for that scenario?

Comment: So, just had fun :) see my answer and thanks for the education with sequence().

Answer (score 1):

So, heavily based on the answer by @JvdV, but wanted to make it a bit more independent so it now works in other columns.

[image]

Needed to label the columns and then use month() and now() with vlookup.
Also works when on a different sheet - but have to add the sheet names to the ranges.